# Sharing objects with jersey json REST client

Tags: java, json, rest, jersey, jackson

I have written a REST service using jersey which maps a object-structure to a json-result, like:

```
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Path("/orders/{id}")
public Order getById(@PathParam("id") String orderId) {
     return orderService.getById(id); // Simplified
}
```

It works perfectly and returns the `Order` object structure as a JSON structure.

Now a (jersey) client accesses this REST service and gets those JSON structure back. It can parse it as a JSON structure, but it would be nice to map it back to (the server's) object structure.

But the server's objects contain many JPA-Annotations and other `import`s the client does not know about.

How can I share anyway my server object structure as (unannotated?) POJOs to my client? TIA!

Comment: Does the client code have access to the Java object on the server-side?

Comment: @thatidiotguy No, it has not. They exists in different web-application-context far away from each other ...

Comment: Good question. I cannot tell you anything but the obvious: write a simpler version of the object and put it in a separate jar that you can include in the client, and extend it for the server so that you've got everything you need. I've done it quite a few times, but I'd like to know if there is a better way.

Answer (score 2):

Try a java generator from json https://javafromjson.dashingrocket.com/